# Unable to use re.compile()

Tags: python

> This program is a very simple example of webscraping. The programs goal is to go on the internet, find a specific stock, and then tell the user the price that the stock is currently trading at. However, I run into the issue in the code that when I compile it, this error message comes up:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "HTMLwebscrape.py", line 15, in <module>
   price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 210, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

> Below is the actual script of the program. I've tried finding ways to solve this code, but so far, I've been unable to. I've been running this on Python 3 and using Submlime Text as my text editor. Thank you in advance!

```
import urllib
import re 
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import  URLError

symbolslist = ["AAPL","SPY","GOOG","NFLX"]

i=0

while i < len(symbolslist):
    url = Request("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL&ql=1")
    htmlfile = urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex  = '<span id="yfs_184_'+symbolslist[i] + '"">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print (price)
    i+=1
```

Comment: Convert htmltext to a string. It's currently a bytes string

Comment: When I convert it to htmltext to a string the output is simply [],[],[],[]. It doesn't actually give the value of the stock. Would you happen to know why this happens?

Comment: And of course, the way you do that is to `decode` it using an appropriate codec.  e.g. `htmltext = htmlfile.read().decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @KeshavSota -- There could be lots of reasons.  e.g. your [regex could be wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/748858) ;-) or the site could be detecting that you're trying to scrape it programatically and giving you a response that you don't expect.

Comment: you can try `re.findall(pattern,htmltext.decode("UTF-8"))`

Comment: When I do this, all I get is: [] [] [] []. I don't actually get any values. Any reason why this happens?